# Could a pic32 run for thousands of years?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, reliability

By estimates based on known parameters of IC aging, could a standard pic32, if it is kept running in a vacuum or inert gas filled chamber, run for thousands of years or would effects like electro migration, dopant redistribution and thermal stresses(Ones that occur even in the stable  temperature environment) break the chip long before then?

Comment: What does Microchip say? They are the only ones who might possibly know for sure. You would need long-term test data to even begin to extrapolate to this length of time, and I can't imagine anyone is willing to pay for such a test.

Comment: Microchip doesn't specify any figures, I was just looking for some estimates....

Comment: I'm certain that if you're a consumer who's willing to pay the premium to get such numbers, you will get something like an MTBF. Certainly, only after signing NDAs, and with a very specified usage scenario.

Comment: The short answer is NO … no (active, running) assembly based on soldered joints (eg surface mounted components on a board) will have lifetimes this long. Start here: http://webparts.mentor.com/flotherm/support/supp/flostress/tutorial/soldier_joint_life.pdf  The passivated silicon chip itself with welded gold wires might have a lifetime of several hundred years. Look at the lifetime of glass recording media to get some insight, but any assemblies have a complex set of chemical structures that will break down simply due to time (and the effects you note) and background radiation.

Comment: failure mode: tin whiskers!

Comment: I would not have put this on hold. I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: It's only opinion-based if nobody can find a good study.

Comment: `kept running in a vacuum` ... vacuum interferes with heat dissipation (eg. thermos bottle) .... it also causes sublimation of material (outgassing) which could lead to shortened lifespan of the device

Comment: Start with the lowest common denominator: Flash retention time. Orders of magnitude below what you are asking.

Comment: On a similar note, a *mean time to failure* way above ten years does *not* imply half of the devices will last that long in continuous operation. Rather, within the lifetime claimed, the supplier expects few devices to fail: with one million devices and a life-time of 10 years, an expected failure of 333 devices corresponds to an MTTF of 30.000 years. Don't expect your batteries to last that long.